# angular.translate not working in the context of <br> in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working with AngularJS and since a few days I try to implement translations using 'angular.translate' of Pascal Precht. This works in general as following:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'config', 'pascalprecht.translate'])

.config(function ($translateProvider)

{
     $translateProvider.translations("en", 
     {
         "GAME_ERROR": "Some error description!",
         "GAME_VALUES": "You got something",
     });

     $translateProvider.preferredLanguage("en");
})
```

**game.html**

```
<th colspan="2" translate="GAME_ERROR"><br translate="GAME_VALUES"></th>
```

When writing the variable `"GAME_VALUES"` this one is not shown. Working with `<span>` neither helps:

```
<th colspan="2" translate="GAME_ERROR"><br><span translate="GAME_VALUES"></span></th>
```

At another place I have the same kind of construct - there the workaround with `<span>` works.

What needs to be done to get this set?

Comment: A br doesn't have any inner text, and for the rest, you don't have any translation provided for language "en"

Comment: Thanks. <br> and no inner text - okay. But why does a <span> does not help instead? Regarding `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage` I corrected my typo.

Comment: When you use the translate directive on the TH Element die childrens will be overwritten by the directive. Therefore the only thing you should see is "Some error description!". The whole innerHTML of the element will be overwritten by the text. If you want to have both text side by side use the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put translation inside an html element, all the child elements will be overwritten by the translation value. Instead you can try the translate filter:

```
<th colspan="2">{{ 'GAME_ERROR' | translate}} <br> {{ 'GAME_VALUES' | translate}}</th>
```

or create two span elements:

```
<th colspan="2"><span translate="GAME_ERROR"></span><br><span translate="GAME_VALUES"></span></th>
```

Comment: Great. The 2 spans had been the solution :-)